# TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/

Tags: python, html, django, templates, error-handling

I'm following a video tutorial but Im getting an error.
The only differance is that author uses Subline Text, while i use VSCode
what is causing the error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ftmE.png)

here's my views code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("Inforamation about")

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

here's my urls code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('home/', views.home),
]
```

and my settings code:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you show location of `templates` folder in the project and your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

Update the directory path to use full path:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Comment: I've tried `import os` and  `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`, still get error.

Comment: Can you screenshot the error page?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by changing your folder structure. Your folder structure for the templates should look like this:

```
mysite
----|templates
     ----|mysite
          ----|home.html
```

After that, change your template path from `'home.html'` to `'mysite/home.html'`.